Comparing large 3d datasets for Grid map data
I am working on Grid maps.Grid maps are a representation of the environment in terms of 2d or 3d cells which store a value in them that can be plotted to make a map of the area.
I am having a lot of datasets which is data of these grid maps  of an area with 3 3d arrays x y and z of size 501x624x94 storing x, y and z coordinates and there is a value assigned to a variable prob which is also of the same size. I have three different kinds of these dataset where this parameter probably is having different kind of values. How do i compare these datasets in terms of visual or statistical parameter or some graphs or surface plots?

You can easily do it in Matlab and/or Python, do you need a code?

@NaveedAhmed if you tell me the approach I can look at it and try myself. But sure you can give a code too.
